# Cannot acces React State child element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>   console.log(this.state.kirja.tyyppi.id);

I want to acces tyyppi.id element
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN7Gr.png

This is my json
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxP5X.jpg

```
class Child extends React.Component{

    state = {
        kirja: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("http://example.com/api/kirja/"+this.props.match.params.id)
            .then(res => {
                const kirja = res.data;
                console.log(kirja)
                this.setState({ kirja });
            })
    }


    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        console.log(this.state.kirja.tyyppi.id);
    return ()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have some developer friends share them this question and see if they can understand anything, you need to provide more code

Comment: is your json in the state ?

Comment: Yes it is, this.state.kirja.tyyppi returns this https://i.imgur.com/oqGnL49.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your initial state for `kirja` is empty array.

Thats why you are not able to access `this.state.kirja.tyyppi.id` in `render()`

```
 render() {

   if(this.state.kirja && this.state.kirja.tyyppi) {
      console.log(this.state.kirja.tyyppi.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks really much!! you made my day! used so much time to try fix this before asking!

Answer (score 0):

In your state.kirja.tyyppi you don't have id.

You didn't save kirja in your state.

Comment: Yes i save it, i just didnt included that code in op. fixed now

Comment: its ok, this is what i get when i console log whole state https://imgur.com/a/mZsjuSp